# Passing many functions as arguments in a big function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a convergence algorithm for a multivariable function. The group of functions are as such:

```
def f(x,r,d): 
if r**2 - x**2 < 1e-15:
    return w0 + 2*d
else: return w0 + 2*d - 2*sqrt(r**2 - x**2)

def g(x,r,d): return 1/f(x,r,d)

def simpsons(function,size,lower_bound,upper_bound, **vars):
delta_x = (upper_bound - lower_bound)/(size - 1)
x = np.linspace(lower_bound,upper_bound,size)
points = (function(x, **vars))

result = (delta_x/3)*(points[0] + points[-1] + 2*sum(points[2:size - 2:2]) + 4*sum(points[1:size - 1:2]))
return result

def H(function,size,lower_bound,upper_bound, **vars): return simpsons(function,size,lower_bound,upper_bound, **vars)/V(**vars) - K
```

Here is my convergence algorithm:

```
def find_zero(function,eps,alpha, **vars):
error = 1
k = 1
result = init_value

while abs(error) > eps:
    error = function(**vars)
    result -= alpha/k*error
    k += 1

return result
```

I will later on describe a list of r to pass through the functions and in the end, solve for d. I do it like so:

```
for i in range(len(R)):
    d[i] = find_zero(H, eps, alpha, function = g, size = size, lower_bound = x0, upper_bound = xf, r = R[i], d = init_value)
```

But I got this error:
TypeError: find_zero() got multiple values for argument 'function'

How do I fix this?

Comment: in your call to `find_zeros()`, you are passing `H` as a positional argument for the function parameter, and then later also pass `g` to the function parameter as a keyword argument with `function=g`. you need to pack those parameters as a dict, and then not unpack them.

Comment: Please read [mre] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure the code appears here exactly as you actually have it - as indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. I tried indenting the code lines in each of the blocks but for some reason it didn't let me do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `find_zero(H, eps, alpha, function = g, size = size, ...)`, you're passing `H` as the first positional value, which is named `function` in the definition of `find_zero`. You're also passing `g` as a keyword argument named `function`. Those aren't compatible!

If you don't want a keyword argument to be mistakenly bound to a named argument that you intend to pass postionally, you can make that argument positional only in the declaration.

```
def find_zero(function, eps, alpha, /, **vars):
   ...
```

In this definition, the arguments `function`, `eps` and `alpha` are all positional only, as they're before the `/` in the function signature. You must pass three arguments positionally when you call this function, and keyword arguments that happen to match the positional argument names will still end up in `vars`.

Positional-only arguments have been in Python since version 3.8 (see [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/)). If you're using an earlier version, you're out of luck and you'll need to rename either the positional or the keyword argument.